# select a column according to specific integer value in database string field

Tags: sql, sqlite

[image: database table]

I want to select id in the database table where allot field have a specific integer value in the string.

example:-  In the allot column I want to search value 26 in Comma(,) separated string, here result should be id=72

Answer (score 1):

Fix your data structure!  You should be using a junction/association table with one row per value and per id.  That is the SQL way to represent the data.  Why is your structure bad?

- Data should be stored using the appropriate type.  Numbers should be stored as numbers, not strings.
- Columns should contain one value.
- Databases have great data structures for storing lists of values.  The best known one is *tables*.  Strings are not the appropriate data structures.
- SQL engines have (relatively) poor string processing capabilities.
- Operations on strings do not (in almost all cases) take advantage of indexes and other engine optimizations.
- If these are ids, then foreign key relationships should be properly declared.

Sometimes, we are stuck with other people's really, really bad design decisions.  In those cases, you can use `like`:

```
SELECT p.id
FROM Prospects p
WHERE ',' || allot || ',' like '%,26,%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `LIKE` operator you should be able to solve your requirement. Considering that your table name is Prospects:

```
SELECT id FROM Prospects
WHERE allot LIKE '%,26,%'
```

**EDIT-1**: You can narrow down the search finer by adding additional commas in the query as mentioned here!

**EDIT-2**: To additionally handle scenarios, you can have the same query with a *UNION* like this. This is ***not something that you should be*** looking to implement, but implement a stored procedure to check these scenarios and handle it in your logic.

```
SELECT id FROM Prospects
WHERE allot LIKE '%,26,%'

UNION

SELECT id FROM Prospects
WHERE allot LIKE '%,26%'

UNION

SELECT id FROM Prospects
WHERE allot LIKE '%26,%'
```

Hope this answers your question!

Comment: if I have 26 and 126 both values then it effects on the result accuracy

Comment: Updated my answer!

Comment: if the string is 26,126,261 then?

Comment: @Manojkumar, basis on what is provided - you could do the additional scenarios. If you have additional questions, then you may post newer questions!

Answer (score 0):

try the commend `'SELECT id FROM (table_name) WHERE allot LIKE '%,26,%'`
the '%x%' will look for anything with an x in it in the provided column
basically if you find something with x give it to me

Comment: if I have string 10,15,26 in a field then the result will not be accurate